# Python urlretrieve a file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to deploy an application on the GAE.
My python script downloads images using the `urlretrieve` function from the `urllib.request` package:

```
urlretrieve(img_url,os.path.join(os.getcwd(),img_dir,str(img_name) + '.jpg'))
```

It works fine, as long as I am running the script locally (to save the images locally), but I am unable to find an alternative to doing the same with the GCS.

I would appreciate if someone could point me towards how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: how it doesn't work for you? you get an error? which error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) shows how to use a couple of simple methods to read and write to Cloud Storage buckets.

Instead of `urlretrieve`, just grab the image's contents and then write the response to a file in Cloud Storage.

```
image_binary = urllib.urlopen(img_url).read()
```

And say you modify the Cloud Storage samples slightly to:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

def create_file(self, filename, contents, mime_type='image/jpeg'):

  write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
  gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                      'w',
                      content_type=mime_type,
                      retry_params=write_retry_params)
  gcs_file.write(contents)
  gcs_file.close()

  # Maybe do other too stuff like make the file publicly
  # accessible
```

And call that to write the file.

Comment: It did work as expected :) PS: Sorry for the late reply